# Increment HTML element ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to increment the id of 2 HTML elements on a button click, `hwAddition` and `itemNumber`. You can see the HTML below:

```
<div id="hwAddition">
    <div id="itemNumber" style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: large;">Item #</div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="hwDescription" style="text-decoration: underline;">Description</label>
            <form:textarea id="hwDescription" type="text"
                class="form-control short" path="hwDescription"
                name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" maxlength="100"
                rows="2" style="resize: none;" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="hwSerialNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Serial
                #</label>
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwSerialNumber"
                name="hwSerialNumber" placeholder="Serial #" maxlength="100" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="hwModelNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Model
                #</label>
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwModelNumber"
                name="hwModelNumber" placeholder="Model #" maxlength="100" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

The jQuery that I've written in order to do this is shown below:

```
var count = 1;

$(function() {
    $("#hwAddition").attr('id', 'hwAddition' + count);
    $("#itemNumber").attr('id', 'itemNumber' + count);
});

$('#hwAdditionButton').click(
    function() {
        $("#itemNumber" + count).clone().attr('id', 'itemNumber' + (count+1));
        $("#hwAddition" + count).clone().attr('id', 'hwAddition' + (count+1))
                .insertAfter("#hwAddition" + count);            
        count++;
    });
```

My issue is that for some reason, the `hwAddition` ids are incrementing correctly, but the `itemNumber` ids are not. You can see this in the image below where, after 3 clicks there is `hwAddition1`, `hwAddition2`, `hwAddition3`, but only `itemNumber1`, `itemNumber1`, `itemNumber1`. Any insight as to why itemNumber id isn't incrementing would be appreciated.[image: inspect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your code? You must miss out the code to increase "ID" for itemNumber.

```
$('#hwAdditionButton').click(
    function() {                
        let clonedObj = $("#hwAddition" + count).clone().attr('id', 'hwAddition' + (count+1));
        clonedObj.find("#itemNumber" + count).attr('id', 'itemNumber' + (count+1));                
        clonedObj.insertAfter("#hwAddition" + count);
        
        count++;
    });
```

Comment: @CDAtheProgrammer, I just tested my code and I confirmed that it worked as expected. [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/wUc9OjkkkcXR)